# How can I change this div with same search_key when I click next button?

Tags: python, django, django-models, jinja2

This is the views.py that retrieve 6 image urls from instagram.First time everything is ok but How can I change shown 6 images in home.html file(that is retrieve 6 new images) when I click the next button?

```
def home(request):
    trends  = []
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        if request.POST.get('q'):
            search_key = request.POST.get('q').replace(" ","") 
            getImageFromInstagram(search_key)
        else:
            search_key = ''
        veriler = hashTags.objects.values_list('hashTag',flat=True)
        line = hashTags(hashTag=search_key,trends=search_key,image_url=tagUrl)
        line.save()
        return render(request, "home.html", {'trends':trends,'urls':urls,'hashtags':veriler})

def getImageFromInstagram():
    tagUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+ search_key +'/media/recent?client_id=Hidden for security'
    q = requests.get(tagUrl).json()
    urls = [ q['data'][i]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] for i in range(6)] 
    return urls
```

end home.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 timeline">
    {%for image_url in urls%} 
       <img src="{{image_url}}">
    {% endfor%}
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Next</button>
```

Comment: you want to retrieve another 6 images from instagramm when you click `next`?

Comment: yes, exactly.When I click next, div class should change with new images

Comment: @doniyor Can you help about that?

Comment: I will try, give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

your form

```
<form action="{% url 'home' %}?next_url={{ next_url }}">
   <div class="col-md-8 timeline">
   <input name="q" type="text">
   {%for image_url in urls %} 
      <img src="{{image_url}}">
   {% endfor%}
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Next</button>
</form>
```

your views.py

```
def home(request):
    trends  = []
    if request.method == 'GET':  
        q = request.GET.get('q', '').replace(" ","") 
        next_url = request.GET.get('next_url', None)
        urls, next_url = getImageFromInstagram(q=q, next_url=next_url)
        # .. your other code
        return render(request, "home.html", {
             'trends': trends,
             'urls': urls, 
             'next_url': next_url,
        })

def getImageFromInstagram(q="", next_url=None):
    if next_url is not None:
        res = requests.get(next_url).json()
        urls = [ res['data'][i]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] for i in range(6)]                   
    else:    
        tagUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+ q+'/media/recent?client_id=Hidden for security'
        res = requests.get(tagUrl).json()
        urls = [ res['data'][i]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] for i in range(6)] 

    next_url = res['pagination']['next_url']
    return urls, next_url
```

but I didnot test it.

Comment: it gave error like thisJSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) because of urls, next_url = getImageFromInstagram(q=q, next_url=next_url)  .

Comment: Is it possible that making this stuff by using the django paginator?